# Unable to "open" services for Windows 7 32 bit anymore

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 32 bit laptop

I used to be able to open the services but it doesnt open anymore.

I have tried opening it by...
- typing "services" in the search box
- going to Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\services

When I click on it, nothing happens.  I cant see any errors in event viewer either.

This laptop is part of a domain, and my id has admin privileges.  I can open add/remove programs, install/uninstall stuff etc.  But services don't open.  I have also tried to be on the domain (VPN into work) to make sure its not related to domain not reachable etc.

Not sure how to figure this out.

Thanks
A

Comment: Probably talk with your IT department.

Comment: What about opening empty console and adding services snap-in manually?

Comment: Added the "services" to an empty console manually.  The addition happens and then when I click on the services to open it....it just hangs (Not responding)

Comment: Can you open any other snap-in from that list? And have you tried doing that in safe mode?

Comment: What if you go to Start, type "services.msc", then right-click and Run as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the culprit, but i went in add/remove programs, sorted by date installed and then uninstalled a whole bunch of programs till a certain date that I knew everything worked right and restarted the machine.  After that services opens up now.  Thanks for everyone's help.